# can we use solr as persistent store for apache ignite?

Tags: solr, ignite

I have been working to integrate solr and apache ignite.....while I am trying to run the program write 
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot enable write-behind (writer or store is not provided) for cache
 this error is shown 
 CacheConfiguration textMetaConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>("textMetaCache");

```
    textMetaConfig.setWriteThrough(true);
    textMetaConfig.setReadThrough(true);
    textMetaConfig.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    textMetaConfig.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
    textMetaConfig.setWriteBehindFlushSize(40960);
    textMetaConfig.setWriteBehindFlushFrequency(1);
    textMetaConfig.setWriteBehindFlushThreadCount(5);
    textMetaConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    textMetaConfig.setIndexedTypes(String.class, TextMeta.class);
```

this is how i have configured cache

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `CacheStore` interface to integrate with any kind of persistence storage. Out of the box Ignite provides Cassandra store implementation and JDBC store implementation which covers most of the regular relational databases. For anything else you will have to create your own implementation. And in any case, the store must be configured via `CacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(..)` configuration property. Please refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store